# PYTHON - creating multiple lists in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to put together a programming project at my university, but I'm stuck. The "math" part I've got covered, but I need help with lists and loops in Python.

I'm working with graphs, let me show one example, to make it clearer:
[3 node graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W64QU.png)

As you can see, I have 3 nodes in it and 2 edges, nothing fancy. I need to compute the closest route between each pair of nodes, and I have that covered already. Now I need to put it either in ***n*** lists, ***n*** elements each, or in a ***n x n***, so either:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [1, 0, 1]
c = [2, 1, 0]
```

or a table (or matrix?) like this:
[table 3x3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFBox.png), where I only really need the part with the white background.

When I read data to work on, I put each node into a list, as a new element, so with these 3 steps I gradually get:

```
lw = []
lw = ['a']
lw = ['a','b']
lw = ['a','b','c']
```

Is there any way, to create empty lists out of elemnts of ***lw***? I would really like to name them like ***dis_a***, ***dis_b***, ***dis_c*** etc. I tried to do it with a dictionary, but then I couldn't manipulate with those lists, like I usually do. And truth be told, I'd much prefer the solution using lists, as I already have a latter part of the program written for this.

EDIT:
Ok, so one of you asked for input/output to make my question clearer. Mmy input is:

```
lw = ['a','b','c']
```

my desired output is:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```

or something like that (lists that can be easly identified with the nodes, that I have listed in ***lw***)

EDIT2:

Ok, so now I have a number of lists created like this (still sticking to the example):

```
dis['a']
dis['b']
dis['c']
```

I have a working command

```
path[X][Y]
```

which on input takes the names of the nodes (as in ***lw*** list ex. 'a'), and on input returns a list of

nodes on the shortest path from X to Y. What I need to be doing now, is to take the length of it with

```
len(path[X][Y])
```

And substract 1 from it (it's counting the "starting" point as well, so it's correcting it). Then I have

to put this number in a corresponding place in a list. I would like to do it in a loop, so it would

automatically append numbers to existing lists, so I would automatically get from

```
dis['a'] = []
dis['b'] = []
dis['c'] = []
```

to

```
dis['a'] = [0, 1, 2]
dis['b'] = [1, 0, 1]
dis['c'] = [2, 1, 0]
```

Don't worry, about it calculating the path twice (ex. from ***a*** to ***b*** and then from ***b*** to ***a***), It doesn't have to be perfect ;) I tried to create such method, but I have no idea, how to store the results in said lists (or if I'm even correct). Here is my proposition:

```
def lo():   
    for i in range(0, len(lw)):
        for j in range (0, len(lw)):
        dis[i].append(path[lw[i]][lw[j]])
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of the desired output to make the question clearer?

Comment: "Is there any way, to create empty lists out of elemnts of lw?" Could you also clarify that statement ? You can create empty lists out of anything (or out of nothing for that matter) so this doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @kjubus Thanks for that.  ComputerFellow's answer already gives you a way to achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What couldn't you manipulate with a dictionary?

`dis_a`, `dis_b`, `dis_c`... could as well be `dis['a']`, `dis['b']` and `dis['c']`...

You could do:

```
dis = {}
for elem in lw:
    dis[elem] = []
    # ...
```

Want to loop over all `dis`-es now?

```
for elem, val in dis.iteritems():
    print elem    # your a, b, or c
    print val     # your [] corresponding to a, b, or c
```

---

If you want to add elements, and find min and max (as requested in the comments):

Let's say initially `dis['a']` gets `[0, 1, 2]`

and ...

```
dis['b'] = [1, 0, 1]
dis['c'] = [2, 1, 0]
```

and now you want to add a new item to all of the `dis`-es...

```
item = 5
for elem in dis:
    dis[elem].append(item)
```

and now you want to find the max ...

```
for elem in dis:
    print max(dis[elem])
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in python (and not much of a programmer either, rather a beginner, I'd say), but when I Do it like you show in the first part, I can print all the created ***dis*** lists, and get a result:
print(dis)
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}

but how do I get to add values to them, find max/min etc?

Comment: @kjubus - I suggest reading through [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial). (If you're using Python 2, then use [the Python 2 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial) instead). But briefly, to access the lists in your dictionary, you can do `dis['a']`, `dis['b']`, etc. To append the number 1 to list `a`, you can do `dis['a'].append(1)`. I hope that and the tutorial links are enough to get you started.

Comment: Note: to find out more about dictionaries, [the dictionary section of the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) will help you the most. (As with my other comment, that's a link to the Python 3 tutorial. [If you're using Python 2, use this link instead](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).)

Comment: @computerfellow thank you! I think that it does finally explain and solves my problem to me :)

Comment: `d = {k:[] for k in lw}`

Comment: @ComputerFellow accepted. Now I have a diffrent problem. Please, see an EDIT2 in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm correct you want to dynamically create variables.
Here is short answer, for more information checkout this post [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop) Actually there you can find different approaches like using a dict.

```
>>> lw = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for l in lw:
        exec("{prefix}{var}=[]".format(prefix="dis_", var=l)) 

>>> dis_a
        []

>>> dis_b.append('some')
>>> dis_b
        ['some']
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Using `exec` has all kinds of security problems, and should only **ever** be done by someone who really knows what they're doing. The OP has said that he's a Python beginner, so he should *not* be using `exec`.

Comment: @rmunn yep, you are definitely right.